# How to add meta description, keywords, custom title to a category template

Tags: categories, customization

I use custom category templates for a few of my categories. Ex: cat-12.php and so on. I use the Fv Simpler Seo and presently it doesnt seem to support an option to edit category templates.

Considering that I use custom category templates, is there a function or a way I include custom meta description and custom title (over riding the default category name that is picked up as the title) without having to use a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for meta description of the category you can use followinf dunction

```
//META DESCRIPTION FUNCTION
function seometadescription(){
        global $post, $posts;
    if ( is_single() || is_page() ) : 
        $customDesc = 'meta_desc';
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                $descriere = get_post_meta($post->ID, $customDesc, true);
            endwhile; 
        endif; 

    elseif( is_category() ):
        $descriere = category_description();
    elseif( is_front_page() ) : 
        $descriere = 'some words for front page description';
    endif; 
    $customMetaDesc = '<meta name="description" content="'.$descriere.'" />';
        echo $customMetaDesc;
}
// end meta desc function
```

$customDesc = is a custom field that I used for post and pages description
If you have not ser a page as front page replace is_front_page() with is_home

For META keywords I found a function on this [web site](http://www.webmediaserv.ro/blog-web-design-development/keyword-uri-seo-pentru-wordpress-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, most category template files do start with `get_header` and then you can add between the `content=""`, but make sure you don't conflict with any PHP scripts.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="title" content="" />
<meta name="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a closer look at custom category templates.
There **must** be an option to edit them.
May be not through dashboard, may be right in theme or plugin folder.
I think it's impossible that there is no option to edit templates.

Comment: Your answer is quite vague. The category template starts with the get header...

Comment: You have distinct file which respond for displaying content of this category. Right?
In this case you can replace get_header() with content of header.php and edit title and description.

Comment: I don't think that is a good practice to put the header contents directly into the category template files.

Comment: agree, it's not a good practice, but it works :).
Another solution - you may use conditional tag is_category() [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Comment: Probably.. will have to give that a try, if there is indeed no other method